# Invoking multiple playbooks with include inside a block of Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to have a block in Ansible which will invoke multiple playbooks using include if a specific flag is set. I am trying to achieve something similar to below:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - block:
      - include: script1.yml
      - include: script2.yml
      - include: script3.yml
     when: flag|bool
```

This snippet throws an error stating *ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <type 'bool'>*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The plays can't be included in a block. Quoting from [ansible.builtin.include Synopsis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html#synopsis)

> Files with a list of plays can only be included at the top level.

As a result, only [Play keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play) can be applied. The condition *when* is not among them.